# How to add a title field to each p-column using ng-template

Tags: html, angular, templates, primeng

I am new to ng-templates.  I have successfully made it so each column correctly represents each name, but was trying to add a title field to each one so that a tooltip will hover with the full name incase the name is larger than the data cell.  The name field is part of a p-datatable...CRUD version.

Thanks!!!  Below is a code snippet.

```
  <p-column field="name" header="Name" [sortable]="true" > 
    <ng-template  let-con="rowData"  title="rowData" >       
         <span title="rowData"></span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
```

Comment: **Please tell everynody that PrimeFaces  is not PrimeNG. PrimeNG is on the primefaces.org website, but has mo relation to the primefaces framework, read the tag info

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea what p-datatable is, but normally data binding is done using property binding with square brackets like this:

```
[title] = "rowData"
```

Where "rowData" is a property of your component class.

Answer (score 0):

title="{{rowData}}" (change it in your span tag) should do the trick!